# SpringBoot AngularJS webSocket integration

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I'm trying to create webSocket on springBoot application.
this is config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/sub");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/send");
}

@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
}

@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
}

@Override
public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
}

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
}

@Override
public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers) {
}

@Override
public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Now from AngularJS I'm trying to connect to websocket using SockJS and Stomp

```
    var socket = new SockJS('/api/ws');
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({}, function (frames) {
            stompClient.subscribe('/subs/hello', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

When I open console I get this message:

> admin-components.js:112173 WebSocket connection to 'wss://proxy.beta.corp.payment21.com/api/ws/135/hwq2yv3q/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

After 30 seconds I get this:

> VM333 sockjs.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Incompatibile SockJS! Main site uses: "1.4.0", the iframe: "1.0.0".
>       at s (VM333 sockjs.min.js:2)

And after 30 more seconds:

[image]

And it is working...

When I go to network to see details in the frames it says

> (Opcode -1)

What is the problem here? Is it the spring configuration or SockJS?

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-fallback-sockjs-enable) the supported client SockJS version is 1.0.x

> On the browser side, applications can use the sockjs-client (version 1.0.x). It emulates the W3C WebSocket API and communicates with the server to select the best transport option, depending on the browser in which it runs.